# SQL query to retrieve distinct elements using a date

Tags: sql

imagine you have the following table:

```
table1:

| sensor_id | event_type | value | date             |
|----------------------------------------------------
| 2         | 2          | 2     | 2015:10:05 12:45 |
| 2         | 2          | 54    | 2015:10:05 15:45 |
| 2         | 3          | 7     | 2015:10:05 14:05 |
| 3         | 2          | 5     | 2015:10:05 00:05 |
| 3         | 2          | 5     | 2015:10:05 14:05 |
```

And you want to retrieve the **last value** for all the sensor_ids and event_types, sorted by sensor_id and event_type, so, the result should be:

```
| sensor_id | event_type | value | date             |
|----------------------------------------------------
| 2         | 2          | 54    | 2015:10:05 15:45 |
| 2         | 3          | 7     | 2015:10:05 14:05 |
| 3         | 2          | 5     | 2015:10:05 14:05 |
```

Can anyone help me with the query?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work:

```
select sensor_id, event_type, value, date
from table1 T1
where date>= all ( select max(date) from table1 T2 where
T1.sensor_id = T2.sensor_id and T1.event_type = T2.event_type)
order by sensor_id, event_type
```

Answer (score 1):

Return a row if there exists no later row with same id:

```
select sensor_id, event_type, value, date
from tablename t1
where not exists (select 1 from tablename t2
                  where t2.sensor_id = t1.sensor_id
                    and t2.event_type = t1.event_type
                    and t2.date > t1.date)
order by sensor_id, event_type
```